# Single word for "thin slice"

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought of *slither*, but I ruled it out as it has negative connotations that I wish to avoid in the context.

I would use the word in a phrase like "a thin slice of bread" or "thinly sliced carrots."

Comment: I think you meant `sliver` instead of `slither`. The word *sliver* has no real negative consequences, but *slither* does.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I meant `sliver`!

Comment: I doubt anyone would say *a sliver of bread*; *slivered carrots* sounds okay, but note that a sliver is a small *piece*, not necessarily a small *slice*. *Wafer* could work well for bread, as it is a thin, small slice. However, if you want a thin slice that isn't necessarily small, then *thin slice* is your best bet.

Comment: -1 because the question is based on a mistaken word and, when edited, will be an obvious question.

Comment: Specifically for carrots and other vegetables, you may also use *julienne* as a culinary term (used as a noun or a verbe).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, "sliver" immediately sprang to mind. Don't know the connotations are that negative?

Comment: I had confused the words `slither` and `sliver`. The word `sliver` will do just fine!

Comment: In the English translations of Lothar-Gunther Buchheim's novel _Das Boot_ the word _sliver_ is used to mean a small amount of anything; it was used as an example of the special meanings that can be attached to words in isolated communities (in this case, the crew of a submarine).

Answer (score 4):

A *shave* is another possibility.

Century Dictionary: A shaving; a thin paring.

American Heritage Dictionary: A thin slice or scraping; a shaving.

Answer (score 3):

Wafer, perhaps? If you can get past the image of the final scene of Meaning of Life, that is.